# Is every a.e. limit of step functions also an a.e. limit of a Cauchy sequence of step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a measure space and $E$ be a Banach space.  A step function from $X$ to $E$ is a measurable function ($E$ takes the Borel measure) with finite image and whose support has finite measure.

If $f:X\to E  $ is an a.e. limit of a sequence of step functions, is it also an a.e. limit of an $L^1$-Cauchy sequence of step functions?

The context for this question is that in *Real and Functional Analysis*, Lang defines $\mathcal{L}^1$ as the space of a.e. limits of Cauchy sequences of step functions, and I wonder if we can say that it is simply the space of a.e. limits of sequences of step functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case in general. For example, take $X=E=\mathbb R$ (with Lebesgue measure) and let $f_n$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[-n,n]$. Then the constant function $1$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n$, but it clearly cannot be an almost everywhere limit of an $L^1$-Cauchy sequence (since it's not in $L^1$).

Recall that $L^1$ (not $\mathcal L^1$) is a space of equivalence classes of functions rather than a space of actual functions (the equivalence relation being that we identify functions that are equal a.e). However $\mathcal L^1$ is a space of actual functions. Indeed it is the space of functions you get by taking the completion of the step functions with respect to the $L^1$ seminorm before quotienting out by the equivalence relation to get $L^1$. When Lang defines $\mathcal L^1$ as the space of a.e. limits of $L^1$-Cauchy sequences of step functions, he ensures that $\mathcal L^1$ is complete in the $L^1$ (semi)norm, and thus once you quotient you get a space which is a complete normed space.

I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thanks!  That's really helpful.

Comment: So why doesn't Lang define $\mathcal{L}^1$ as the space of $L^1$ limits of Cauchy sequences of step functions, if he is just trying to straightforwardly get the completion?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287211/completion-of-proof-of-vi-3-4-completeness-of-l1-in-langs-real-and-functi?rq=1) makes me think it would be an equivalent approach, and maybe more intuitive.

Comment: Oh, I think I see why, because to prove that the $L^1$ limit of a Cauchy sequence exists he'll probably have to go through an a.e. uniform limit of a subsequence first anyway.  Unless there is a way to prove more directly that a $L^1$ limit exists, but I can't think of one now.

Comment: You're correct in what you say. A priori it's not clear that the $L^1$ limit of step functions is a function (it's an element of the completion which is a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences). However an a.e limit of functions is a function, and the condition of being a.e limit of an $L^1$-Cauchy sequence then ensures that this function is an "$L^1$ function".